# Pop up message before closing a file

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need a pop-up message to remind the person to check all the information before closing the presentation, with two choices (to cancel or to close it anyway).

```vb
Private Sub PPTApp_PresentationBeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If MsgBox("Confirmo que as informações desta apresentação estão atualizadas no SAP", _
            vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked at the links in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57362717/4497791

Comment: yes, but I could'nt understand how this article works for what I need

Comment: PresentationBeforeClose one of the events that Powerpoint triggers when certain things happen. If you want your code to respond to these events, you must set an event trap, a bit of code that runs when an event "fires". The links in the article eirikdaude4 suggested explain how to set up this event trap. It requires code in a class module and code in your main module to get the class to wake up and listen for events. Here are two other pages that offer useful information:  http://youpresent.co.uk/powerpoint-application-events-in-vba/ and http://www.officeoneonline.com/vba/events_version.html

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
Private Sub PPTApp_PresentationBeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 Dim i As Long
    i = MsgBox("your message will appear here", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
If i = vbNo Then
    'do this command
Else 
  ' do this command

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please help me on how to do it? I open the VBA editor (ALT+F11) added a Class Module and paste the code but it did not work...